# Where do I save the file so python excute it in windows power shell

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am starting to learn python and the ebook I am using is the "learn python the hard way" something like that.

I have completed exercises 0-19 well but I am stuck at exercise 2o, I am requesting for your help to solve it on how to save the file in the script or related so as when I type in the windows power shell I get what is the file.

It can be stupid question for you but it is useful to me please help me. Check the comment in the script.

here is the python script:

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

    def rewind(f):
        f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file) # Is it here where should I put the file or if yes how?

print "First let's print the whole:\n"

print_all(current_file)

print "Let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

print "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

here is the errors I get.

PS D:\pythonprograms> python ex20.py adsense.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex20.py", line 3, in 
    script, adsense.txt = argv
NameError: name 'adsense' is not defined
PS D:\pythonprograms> python ex20.py adsense.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex20.py", line 14, in 
    current_file = open(input_file, adsense.txt) # Is it here where should I put the file or if yes how?
NameError: name 'adsense' is not defined
PS D:\pythonprograms> python ex20.py input_file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex20.py", line 14, in 
    current_file = open(input_file, "adsense.txt", "r") # Is it here where should I put the file or if yes how?
TypeError: an integer is required
PS D:\pythonprograms>

Answer (score 1):

What is the error you are getting? You need to give the file's exact location or make sure both your python file and the text file are in the same directory.

Comment: I have tried to run several times but nothing works, here is the errors. PS D:\pythonprograms> python ex20.py adsense.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex20.py", line 3, in <module>
    script, adsense.txt = argv
NameError: name 'adsense' is not defined
PS D:\pythonprograms> python ex20.py adsense.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex20.py", line 14, in <module>
    current_file = open(input_file, adsense.txt) # Is it here where should I put the file or if yes how?
NameError: name 'adsense' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct place for filename, but You must use "" or '' with filename - 'filename'.
In your code python try find variable, which name is adsense.